# Adding the hash key values

Tags: java, collections

```
public class HashtableDemo {
 static String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    //dictionary can be created using HashTable object
    //as dictionary is an abstract class
    Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();

    //put(key, value)
    ht.put("MIKE", 1);
    ht.put("CHIN", 2);
    ht.put("CHRIS", 3 );
    ht.put("HOLY", 4);

    //looping through all the elements in hashtable
    String str;

    //you can retrieve all the keys in hashtable using .keys() method
    Enumeration names = ht.keys();
     while(names.hasMoreElements()) {

         //next element retrieves the next element in the dictionary
         str = (String) names.nextElement();
         //.get(key) returns the value of the key stored in the hashtable
         System.out.println(str + ": " + ht.get(str) + newLine);

     }
  }
}
```

How can I add the all the key values into a variable, like 1+2+3+4=10?

Comment: I don't see any question...

Comment: how can add the all the key values into a variable,like 1+2+3+4=10

Comment: Check the Java language for "variables".

Comment: like i want to store the addition of all the key values

Comment: The key values are strings.  You want the concatenation of them?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating over the keys, you could simply iterate over the value:

```
int sum = 0;
for (Integer val : ht.values()) {
    sum += val;
}
```

Comment: thanks,I corrected it.Can I use hashtable instead of hash map

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need synchronization, I would recommend using a `Map` instead of the `HashTable`.  As suggested by the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html):

> If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to
>   use HashMap in place of Hashtable.

**Example:**

```
    Map<String, Integer> ht = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    ht.put("MIKE", 1);
    ht.put("CHIN", 2);
    ht.put("CHRIS", 3 );
    ht.put("HOLY", 4);

    int total = 0;
    for(Integer value: ht.values()){
        total+=value;
    }
    System.out.println(total);
```